# Which methods or techniques can I use to solve these differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve these equations by finding an integrating factor and by looking for possible substitutions, without any result. I'm not sure if my algebra needs more practice or if I need to use some non evident method.

The equations are:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{4x+3y+15}{2x+y+7}
$$
and
$$
y(x+y+1)dx+x(x+3y+2)dy=0 
$$

If anyone could show all the steps to solve them I would be really grateful. If not, are there any techniques I could use to solve each of them 'easily'?

Comment: Well, this type of equations can be reduced to homogeneous equation. Just use substitution $y = y^\ast + u$, $x = x^\ast + v$, where $x^\ast$ and $y^\ast$ solve the system $4x^\ast + 3y^\ast + 15 = 0, \; 2x^\ast + y^\ast + 7 = 0$.

Comment: The Wolfram Alpha output involves the root of some sixth degree polynomial, all minus $2x+7$. So it may help to consider $y=z-2x-7$.

Comment: @Evgeny Your solution works , I am just wondering how did you come up with the idea?

Comment: Thank you! It worked for the first one. I can't simplify the second one after the substitution though.

Comment: @DimitriC Well, this method has been told to us when we studied homogeneous equations and those which can be reduced to them. I think the idea is fairly explainable: you see two 'almost' homogeneous linear polynomials, but they have constant terms. You can make this substitution to rule out them and preserve the homogeneity of polynomials.

Comment: Very nice! My book doesn't contain this approach!